# Can I change names of network interfaces arbitrary?

Tags: networking, interface, ifconfig

I have installed OpenWRT on VirtualBox.

There are four interfaces:

- br-lan
- eth0
- eth1
- lo

Why do they call that way? Are they variables? Can I name them arbitrary?

- foo-bar
- xyz0
- xyz1
- bo

Like so:

```
config interface 'wan'
    option proto 'dhcp'
    option ifname 'xyz1' # it is 'eth1' here by default
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can name them whatever you like. You might take a look [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-understanding_the_device_renaming_procedure) or [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91085/udev-renaming-my-network-interface)